# Sql query two columns with relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a  column with name `id_std` in table `account`.

In `account` table I have recursive relation with name `parent_account_id`

I am trying to get all records with `parent_account_id` = the selected `id` with `id_std = 333`, id_std is a unique value of table

Example:

```
id - id_std - parent_account_id - name
 1    333     null                 Name 1
 2    129     1                    Name 2
 3    249     1                    Name 3
```

How to filter with `333` `id_std` and include all records with `parent_account_id = 1` in the same query?

Comment: can you give expected output

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am working on the assumption from your example data that there is only one row where `id_std` = 333, so:

```
select * from account where parent_id = (select id from account where id_std = 333)
```

If there are multiple rows where `id_std` = 333 then:

```
select * from account where parent_id in (select id from account where id_std = 333)
```

(Of course, the above will work even if `id_std` = 333 is unique.)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a self join on account

```
select  a.id, a.id_std, a.parent_account_id, a.name, b.id, b.id_std, b.parent_account_id, b.name
from account a 
inner join  account b on a.id = b.parent_account_id 
 where  a.id_std = 333
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also do a hierarchical query with a limiter so it just takes the first level of hierarchy.

```
select a.* from mytable a
start with id_std = 333
connect by prior id = parent_account_id and prior thename = 'Name 1'
```

here is a fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8dfd/19